# Computing the value of a Taylor Coefficient

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I am having trouble figuring out how to compute the value of the second Taylor coefficient for $e^{\sin(z)}$, with $z=i$. I need to compute the second Taylor coefficient, but I feel after getting help on how exactly to do the first one I can figure it out. This is using $f^k(a)/k!$ of the Cauchy Integral Formula.

Comment: Is this what you mean? $$e^{\sin(z)}$$

Comment: yes, I couldn't figure out how to edit it to look like that.

Comment: I've edited your post. To format it this way, use "e^{\sin(z)}".

Comment: Which coefficient?

Comment: @AdamHughes all the instructions say is 2nd Taylor Coefficient using the equation for f(z) and plugging that into the $f^k(a)/k!$ formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the second (I assume this means $k=2$, i.e. that there is a "zeroth" coefficient).

This is just

$${f''(i)\over 2!}={1\over 2}\cdot{d\over dz}\bigg|_{z=i}(\cos ze^{\sin z}) = {1\over 2}\cdot e^{\sin i}(\cos^2 i -\sin i)$$

Comment: Alright, so I just do the derivative twice? I was confused as to where the (a) came into play, but plugging in $i$ for it makes sense.

Comment: @Heavenly96 that's correct, $a$ is the point at which you are taking it.